# Deep comparison of multi dim array that contains objects

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Consider the following array structure. This is a pseudo syntax where `Table` and `Row` is just an `Array`. And `Row` contains different objects. I use this for an excel sheet like application.

```
Table [Row, Row, Row, ...]
    0: Row
        0: TextEntry {value: "1", active: false}
        1: TextEntry {value: "3", active: false}
        2: NumberEntry {value: 0, active: false}
    1: Row
        0: TextEntry {value: "text", active: false}
        1: TextEntry {value: "8", active: false}
        2: NumberEntry {value: 0, active: false}
    2: Row
        0: TextEntry {value: "1", active: false}
        1: TextEntry {value: "3", active: false}
        2: NumberEntry {value: 0, active: false}
    ...
```

I want to determine if there is a `Row` inside inside `Table`, which identical to another `Row` by comparing the `value` attributes. In this example the `array` on index `0` whould be identical to the one on index `2`.

How could I achieve that in js?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: A mix of two loops would be the most generic way.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz OP only wants to compare one fixed property -> `.value`

Comment: @WaisKamal I tried using a Set for it , and also JSON.stringify, no success as of now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the combination of `some` and `every` function of the Array prototype should be enough. Version with `some` returns a boolean result. Version with `filter` returns the rows themself.
Unless what you wanted to achieve is checking whether the table contains duplicated rows? I added an example of that below.

```
const table = [
  [
      {value: "1", active: false},
      {value: "3", active: false},
      {value: 0, active: false}
  ],
  [
      {value: "text", active: false},
      {value: "8", active: false},
      {value: 0, active: false}
  ],
  [
      {value: "1", active: false},
      {value: "3", active: false},
      {value: 0, active: false}
  ]
];

const rowToFind=[
  {value: "1", active: false},
  {value: "3", active: false},
  {value: 0, active: false}
];


let foundRows=table.filter(m => m.every((el, indx, arr)=>rowToFind[indx].value==el.value));
let foundRowsBoolean=table.some(m => m.every((el, indx, arr)=>rowToFind[indx].value==el.value));

console.log(foundRows);
console.log(foundRowsBoolean);

//Check duplicated rows
let foundDuplicates=table.some((el, indx)=> table.some((el2, indx2)=> indx!=indx2 && el.every((e, indx)=>e.value==el2[indx].value)));
console.log(`Contains duplicates: ${foundDuplicates}`);
```

Comment: Yes 'foundDuplicates' is what I was trying to achieve. Thank you so much!